# ValueError: math domain error using PCA.fit (python)

Tags: python-2.7, pca

As you see, error raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/pca.py",
>   line 86, in _assess_dimension_
>       *(1. / spectrum_[j] - 1. / spectrum_[i])) + log(n_samples)*

**ValueError: math domain error**

I already know that math domain error is caused when we take logarithm of a negative number, but I don't understand how can there be a negative number inside the logarithm?
Can someone tell me what exactly the problem is?

Here is the origin code:

```
    pca = PCA(n_components='mle')
    pca.fit(data)
    joblib.dump(pca, "../../conf/pca.cf")
    data = pca.transform(data)
```

The elements in Matrix are all greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: Just had the same issue. Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921068/math-domain-error-while-using-pca